# Why isn't my workflow sending Emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, exchange-online

I have a SharePoint Online list with an attached workflow which I want to send an email to a predefined address whenever a new list item is created.

I have created the workflow and when an item is created it shows as running without errors and completing successfully but the email doesn't arrive in the destination inbox.

The target destination is an Exchange online mailbox called reception@mydomain.com which is linked to a SharePoint Account (Also called Reception) The Reception account is in the Members group of the site and has Contribute permissions to the list.

I have tested that the mailbox is capable of recieving mail from both internal and exteral sources and successfully received the test messages in both cases.

I have very limited experience with Exchange Online. Can anyone explain why the workflow is not sending emails and, hopefully, give me a step-by-step guide to a fix.

Comment: I have had similar problems with 2013 workflow. If possible, have you tested this with a SP 2010 workflow? They tend not to have the same issues sending emails.

Comment: tried telnet that address of exchange?also make sure that mailbox is receiving mails when you send oob.also suggest to create a 2010 compatible workflow as Matt  advised and check

Answer (score 1):

- Ensure that the workflow sends emails at all by switching it to send to another address to which you have access
- Use the "log to history" action before and after the email action, then review your workflow history to make sure both of these logs appear
- Make sure you always hit Publish when making changes to your workflow and testing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment from Matt I found the answer. 
I was using the default SP2013 workflows which, for some reason, registered as complete but didn't actually send the email to the specified addresses.

When I rebuilt the workflow using the SP2010 workflows option the problem disappeared.